# Is there a possibility to use conditional rules with azure devops extensions?

Tags: azure-devops-extensions

I´m currently developing an azure devops extension in form of a control contribution.
The thing is, that it should only show in certain states eg. "Closed".
So I´ve tried to just set the initial height to 0 and change it when ever i detect the right state.
But apparently the IFrame does not care about that and uses a minimum height of 50px.

Is there a possibility to use ronditional rules like in the normal field conditions?
[conditional rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/assign-conditional-based-values-and-rules?view=azure-devops-2020)

**Edit 31.07.2020** 
I have now implemented the observer and all is working fine, but when I call the SDK.unregister() function nothing happens. 

I´m calling the register method like this:

```
SDK.register("vsts-extensions-Control-ClosedInVersion.ms.vss-work-web.work-item-
form",() => {...})
```

and the unregister method like this:

```
SDK.unregister("vsts-extensions-Control-ClosedInVersion.ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form");
```

There is no feedback when calling "unregister" any suggestions?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: We can use the event [onSaved](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-workitem-extension?view=azure-devops#events) and then call the API to update build. It fired after a work item is saved. For work items in a dialog, you should target the "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-notifications" type to ensure the event is fired since once the dialog is closed this contribution type is unloaded.

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT Thank you for the answer! I should´ve stated, that I´m using the new Extension SDK which is using Reactjs. Which API can I call to update the WorkItemForm Build? and how can I unload the contribution?

Comment: Hi Gruffi,
According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-sdk/#unregister-string-), we should call the function via function unregister(instanceId: string).
In addition, update WorkItemForm, please refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-workitem-extension?view=azure-devops)

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT thank you for your answer. can you give me an example on implementing an observer for my workitemform? As you see in the updated question I tried to use the SDK.register and unregister functions like in the docs. But there is no feedback when I unregister the extension.